# Sync smartsheets to postgres table?

Tags: postgresql, smartsheet-api

Is there a way to copy the contents of a smartsheets table to a postgres table? We would like to schedule this as part of our ETL pipeline. Hoping to avoid using a third party service like zapier or integromat if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Smartsheet data isn't returned as a table, so you'll need to loop over every row, loop over every cell. You could map it if you need to do this regularly.